# How to sort months in List<> in Spring boot - Using Java 8

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sorting, spring-data-jpa

I have list of months, I am setting in the POJO class, While I am setting it, order is not getting sorted. I want to sort it. Sample data looks like -

My POJO Class -

```
public class SamplePojo {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private String type;
   private String name;
   private Integer January;
   private Integer February;
   private Integer March;
   private Integer April;
   private Integer May;
   private Integer June;
}
```

ServiceImpl -

```
List<SamplePojo> sp = new ArrayList<SamplePojo>();
SamplePojo tp1 = new SamplePojo ();
        
        tp1.type("type");
        tp1.name("name");
        tp1.setJanuary(12);
        tp1.setFebruary(2);
        tp1.setMarch(33);
        tp1.setApril(0);
        tp1.setMay(0);
        tp1.setJune(0);
        tp1.setTotal(122);
        sp.add(tp1);
```

Unsorted data -

```
[
    {
        "type": "LLB",
        "name": "Working",
        "total": 0,
        "march": 33,
        "april": 0,
        "may": 0,
        "june": 0,
        "february": 2,
        "january": 12
    },
    {
        "type": "Engineer",
        "name": "Not Working",
        "total": 0,
        "march": 33,
        "april": 0,
        "may": 0,
        "june": 0,
        "february": 2,
        "january": 12
    }
]
```

Wanted to sort -

```
[
    {
        "type": "LLB",
        "name": "Working",
        "january": 11,
        "february": 2,
        "march": 3,
        "april": 3,
        "may": 0,
        "june": 0,
        "total": 0
    },
    {
        "type": "Engineer",
        "name": "Not Working",
        "january": 12,
        "february": 2,
        "march": 33,
        "april": 0,
        "may": 0,
        "june": 0,
        "total": 0
    }
]
```

How can I do this using Spring boot. I am new to this Spring boot and New to this stackoverflow. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Hey @HanufaHannan do you want to sort by January? asc right?

Comment: _Can you please help me_ No, I can't help you because your question is not clear to me. Do you want to convert your POJO to a JSON string and have the month members appear in chronological order in that string? By the way, the member names appear capitalized in the Java code but not so in the JSON. Is that another typo?

Comment: I had to read this several times to make sense of what (I think) you're asking: you want to know how to sort the _display_ output of JSON data. If that's it, I would ask: why does that matter?

Comment: @Abra - I don't wanted to convert POJO to JSON. I wanted to sorted by January - ASCENDING Order. After setter the data into POJO.

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to do. Could you please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Kaan -How to sort, List<MyPOJO> class, based on Month Name ? Sample JSON response I have shared above.

Comment: can you provide a same example of expected output?

Comment: We need to see actual code for what you're actually doing. Your comment above asks for sorting `List<MyPOJO>` when we don't know what `MyPOJO` is. You posted about `SamplePojo`, so.. if that's what you're asking about (?), what does it mean to sort a list of `SamplePojo` objects? There are 8 fields on that class – what is the rule that says one instance of `SamplePojo` is less than another `SamplePojo`? Once you have a rule, make a Comparator, then call `Collections.sort(list, comparator)`.

Comment: @Kaan - I have added ServiceImpl class, please check.

Comment: I suspect that you do not want to sort `SamplePojo` objects itself, but rather months' data inside the output, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort the JSON payload, you can use `@JsonPropertyOrder` annotation

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
  "type",
  "name",
  "January",
  "February",
  "March"
})
public class SamplePojo {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1 L;
  private String type;
  private String name;
  private Integer January;
  private Integer February;
  private Integer March;
  private Integer April;
  private Integer May;
  private Integer June;
}
```

Comment: My eyes!, code conventions, but I think the issue about field naming is from the author. :c

Comment: @JonathanJOhx I just copied the code from op's code above to avoid any confusion for him ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is sorting from the repository by using [Spring Data Repository query keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) by find all `SampleEntity` by following code.

```
@Repository
public interface SampleEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<SampleEntity, Long> {
    List<SampleEntity> findAllByOrderByJanuaryAsc();
}
```

But if you want to sort on the last layer to showing `List of SamplePojo` you can use `stream` and `sorted` by some criteria.

```
List<SamplePojo> lastList = sampleService.findAll();
lastList
    .stream()
    .sorted((sPojo1, sPojo2) -> sPojo1.getJanuary().compareTo(sPojo2.getJanuary()));
```

Comment: Nope, not working

Comment: Sorry, if this doesn't work then I don't get your question. Please `edit your question detailly` so I might help you later.